# iphone facebook icon in screen grab for submission

Tags: iphone, facebook, screenshot, double-submit-prevention

you think putting a Facebook icon in one of your screen grab list for submission would violate the apple sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Does Facebook provide it's icon for third-parties to use? If so, then you should be okay. However, no one can be 100% for sure since history indicates that App Store reviewers are pretty subjective in their reviews. For example, I had an application update rejected because of a UI element that's been in a live app for 6 months because it might be confusing to the user.

I haven't heard of Apple enforcing other company's copyrights and trademarks, but you would want to be careful infringing on Apple's copyrights and trademarks (see [here](http://www.marco.org/98224131)).

Sadly, aside from submitting the app and crossing your fingers, I don't think you'll get a definite answer.

Comment: interesting, thanks gordan! yeah i figure since FB allowed FBconnect for iphone back in march, i figured it would be ok.


all the best.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will protect their own copyrights and trademarks but isn't much interested in third-parties'. Who's to say you didn't get permission from Facebook to use their icon? If Apple rejected you for it, it would put them in the position of requiring you to submit proof to them that you have permission, which means they would be reviewing legal agreements between two other parties... why bother? It's easier for them to approve it and, if Facebook has a problem, let Facebook come after you themselves.

So, in brief, it wouldn't violate the SDK agreement; but you might get grief from Facebook if Facebook finds out about it.